# Why am I getting Template not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following routes:

```
create_admin_path   GET     /app/views/createAdmin/create_admin.html.erb(.:format)  application#createAdmin
```

I have this in routes.rb

```
get "/app/views/createAdmin/create_admin.html.erb", to: "application#createAdmin", as: "create_admin"
```

I have this in the application_controller.rb

```
def createAdmin

end
```

and in the view I have a folder called `createAdmin` which has a file called `create_admin.html.erb`

in the `create_admin.html.erb` I have something like this:

```
<h1> testing is here </h1>
```

Yet I am receiving this error message:

> No route matches [GET] "/app/views/create_admin/create_admin.html.erb"

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views must match in controller name and view file name, that's if you're registering the route to `application#createAdmin`, then the folder must be `application/` and the file `createAdmin`, in camel case as you've named the action and the route, so your file must be called `createAdmin` and must be located in a folder called `application/`.

```
/app/views/application/createAdmin.html.erb.
```

But, there are some things to add:

There's no need to use the ApplicationController to handle such operations, you can easily create a new controller and use it with that purpose instead polluting the ApplicationController.

You don't need to specify the full route to the view as the URI when registering a route, unless it's **that** specifically what want to do.

When working with Ruby use [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Comment: I can't understand what u mean, can u please rephrase your answer. Thanks so much

Comment: Your file must be called `createAdmin` and must be located in a folder called `application/`. `/app/views/application/createAdmin.html.erb`.

Comment: what if I wanted my file to be in `application/app/views/createAdmin/create_admin.html.erb` what changes do I need to make ? Thanks again

Comment: You could specify the file to render in the action `def createAdmin render 'createAdmin/create_admin' end`.

Comment: ur answer haven't solved my problem. I made createAdmin in the following directory `application/. /app/views/application/createAdmin.html.erb`. and I'm getting this error message : `uninitialized constant ApplicationsController`

Comment: never mind I solved it, it should be `get "/app/views/createAdmin/create_admin.html.erb", to: "application#createAdmin", as: "create_admin"` so application and not applicatoins